# List call fails about 10 pages in

Tags: google-surveys

I'm having some trouble with the "list" API call - it works OK for about 10 pages of results (feeding in the value of nextPageToken into subsequent calls), but then I get a 500 error (always at the same point). Is there a limit on the number of pages of results that can be listed?

Also, just confirming - the discovery file has a maxResults parameter but it seems to have no effect - is this correct?

Cheers,
Miles

Answer (score 2):

I'm an engineer at Google. We had a bug related to certain unicode characters in the titles of surveys that was causing some List requests to fail. We've fixed the decoding issue now, so list should be able to work to access the rest of your remaining surveys now.

maxResults is not implemented by the API and should not be used.

Thanks for reaching out about this issue.